# wp_mail() success sent when it is not using header 'content-type:text/html'

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I've been trying to use all the source that can possibly help my problem but it's just not working well.

and this is my code:

```
$subject = 'Pendaftaran Paytren (Daftar-Paytren.net)';
$emaile = 'yukdaftarpaytren@gmail.com';
$message = 'Ada yang daftar<br/>Nama Lengkap : '.$nama.'<br/>Tempat Lahir : '.$tempatlahir.'<br/>Tanggal Lahir : '.$tanggallahir.'<br/>Jenis Kelamin : '.$jeniskelamin.'<br/>Negara : '.$negara.'<br/>Kota Tampat Tinggal : '.$kota.'<br/>Nomor HP : '.$telp.'<br/>Email : '.$email.'<br/>Username : '.$username.'<br/>Pin BB : '.$bb.'<br/>WA : '.$wa;
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'From: Daftar-Paytren.net <yukdaftarpaytren@gmail.com>');                    

    if (wp_mail( $emaile, $subject, $message, $headers )){
        echo "success";
    }else {
        echo wp_mail( $emaile, $subject, $message, $headers );
    }
```

and it was said success as if, but I wasn't receive any mail in my inbox. but if I remove the headers 'Content-type:' thing, so the code will be:

```
$subject = 'Pendaftaran Paytren (Daftar-Paytren.net)';
$emaile = 'yukdaftarpaytren@gmail.com';
$message = 'Ada yang daftar<br/>Nama Lengkap : '.$nama.'<br/>Tempat Lahir : '.$tempatlahir.'<br/>Tanggal Lahir : '.$tanggallahir.'<br/>Jenis Kelamin : '.$jeniskelamin.'<br/>Negara : '.$negara.'<br/>Kota Tampat Tinggal : '.$kota.'<br/>Nomor HP : '.$telp.'<br/>Email : '.$email.'<br/>Username : '.$username.'<br/>Pin BB : '.$bb.'<br/>WA : '.$wa;
$headers = 'From: Daftar-Paytren.net <yukdaftarpaytren@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";                    

    if (wp_mail( $emaile, $subject, $message, $headers )){
        echo "success";
    }else {
        echo wp_mail( $emaile, $subject, $message, $headers );
    }
```

and that'll work and I receive the email but as plain text. I need to set the content type so the email can be read as well.

and I also tried this, still nothing work.

```
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
$headers[] = 'From: Daftar-Paytren.net <yukdaftarpaytren@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
```

What is wrong with my code? please help me.
and please ignore the language on that script.

**UPDATE**

if I used this code:

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'wpdocs_set_html_mail_content_type' );
$emaile = 'yukdaftarpaytren@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Pendaftaran Paytren (Daftar-Paytren.net)';
$message = 'Ada yang daftar<br/>Nama Lengkap : '.$nama.'<br/>Tempat Lahir : '.$tempatlahir.'<br/>Tanggal Lahir : '.$tanggallahir.'<br/>Jenis Kelamin : '.$jeniskelamin.'<br/>Negara : '.$negara.'<br/>Kota Tampat Tinggal : '.$kota.'<br/>Nomor HP : '.$telp.'<br/>Email : '.$email.'<br/>Username : '.$username.'<br/>Pin BB : '.$bb.'<br/>WA : '.$wa;
$headers = 'From: Daftar-Paytren.net <yukdaftarpaytren@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";                   

if (wp_mail( $emaile, $subject, $message, $headers )){
                        echo "sukses";
}else {
echo wp_mail( $emaile, $subject, $message, $headers );
}
// Reset content-type to avoid conflicts -- https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23578
remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'wpdocs_set_html_mail_content_type' );

function wpdocs_set_html_mail_content_type() {
    return 'text/html';
}
```

The email was sent and I was receiving an inbox but, it is sending the subject as file attachment (.txt) with plain text as the content.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to using the filter wp_mail_content_type to set html format instead of headers?

Here is your code with this modification:

```
<?php
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', function($content_type){
    return 'text/html';
});

$emaile = 'yukdaftarpaytren@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Pendaftaran Paytren (Daftar-Paytren.net)';
$message = 'Ada yang daftar<br/>Nama Lengkap : '.$nama.'<br/>Tempat Lahir : '.$tempatlahir.'<br/>Tanggal Lahir : '.$tanggallahir.'<br/>Jenis Kelamin : '.$jeniskelamin.'<br/>Negara : '.$negara.'<br/>Kota Tampat Tinggal : '.$kota.'<br/>Nomor HP : '.$telp.'<br/>Email : '.$email.'<br/>Username : '.$username.'<br/>Pin BB : '.$bb.'<br/>WA : '.$wa;

wp_mail( $emaile, $subject, $message );

// Reswitch to after use text/plain to prevent conflict
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', function($content_type){
    return 'text/plain';
});
?>
```

Hope it will help!

Comment: thank you for your reply. Yes, I was using that before, but still not working.

Comment: that was sending email but still as a plain text. I need to change the text to html type. @Vincent B